# How to pull the first value after a date from one tab into another in google sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a tab in google sheets with a weekly stock price data (columns are date and price). I have another tab with some signals (date and long entry price).

I want to add a column to the first sheet (long entry) that pulls in the first long entry price from the signals tab into the rows after (and between) the signal date and the close date.

For example, in prices, I have:

```
date       | price
2006-01-01 | 30.00
2006-01-07 | 31.00
2006-01-14 | 32.00
2006-01-21 | 33.00
2006-01-28 | 34.00
```

In signals, I have:

```
date       | entry_price
2006-01-03 | 33.30
2006-01-12 | 32.10
```

I want:

```
date       | price | entry_price
2006-01-01 | 30.00 | 
2006-01-07 | 31.00 | 33.30
2006-01-14 | 32.00 | 32.10
2006-01-21 | 33.00 | 32.10
2006-01-28 | 34.00 | 32.10
```

See how it has no entry price for 1/1/2006? Thats because there is no signal before 1/3. And see how the entry price from the 1/12 signal is used for 1/14, 1/21/ and 1/28? Thats because thats the first date after the last signal.

Here's a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Que11TQPWiw7g2lRYCyaFHAWllrtst8l_qvjohI4eH0/edit?usp=sharing) that has this stuff in it.

I'm hoping there's a simple way to do what i want using vlookup, query, etc but I don't know what it is :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, signals!A:B, 2, 1)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks. I think the one issue with this is the use of "is_sorted" to get the closet match. If I add a row to the prices tab for 7/12, then it uses the 7/12 signal. I don't want it to. I want the first use of the 7/12 signal to be 7/13. Does that make sense?

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, SORT(signals!A:B), 2, 1)))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried that but the 1/12 row on prices still has the 1/12 signal data. It should have the 1/7 signal data. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Que11TQPWiw7g2lRYCyaFHAWllrtst8l_qvjohI4eH0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try:  `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, SORT({signals!A:A+1, signals!B:B}), 2, 1)))`

Comment: Yes! That worked! But I have no idea why. Can you tell me what `SORT({signals!A:A+1, signals!B:B})` does? I ran just that part in its own cell and it does something odd... row after row of "1989-12-31" then a bunch of rows with "1"'s and then at the end, a copy of the signals tabs data.

Comment: sure. valid dates are stored in google sheets as numbers. today's date is for example 44028 so all we did was add +1 to this number to turn it into tomorrow. both A and B columns are numbersso then we need to apply this only on dates (A column) so we create arrayed range with curly brackets {} and add +1 only to dates. SORT function makes sure you get the right value even if your dates are not sorted in signals A column chronologically. if there is no date and we add 1 then 0+1=1 chance those 1's.

Comment: and date 1989-12-31 is equal to number 1 coz its a first date you can possibly use in google sheets. since then 44028 days passed up to today's day